# How can i find out the size of a cell with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a popup that pops up right underneathe a `<th>` so it looks like the `<td>` (don't ask why). on 1024 *760 its the same width as the table header cell, but on 1280 it's not as wide. How can i wirte a script to find out the width of my `<th>`? (I'm using jQuery.)

edit:

```
<th id="telephoneTH" width="25%" >
<span  id="telephoneSpan" class="headerShortDetails">Telephone</span><span onclick="showContactPopup();"  class="infoSpans"> ${bean.phoneNumber}</span>
</th>


var width2 = $('#telephoneTH').outerWidth();
alert(width2);
```

error: 'null' is null or not an object

Comment: Or "learn how to catch the fish" and use availWidth and check if there are any css rules for the "th" for a little math exercise

Comment: @pekka i think so. I have got the following in my head tag  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.5.js"></script>

Comment: @user: Then yes, you're using jQuery. If you're using a library like that, it's important to mention it in your question, because libraries make a lot of this stuff a *lot* easier by providing the functionality. People can target their answers appropriately. I've edited your question to say.

Comment: @pekka @t.j. ok this works var width2 = $('telephoneTH').width; but it returns "12%" which is not recognised by popup sizing function since its expecting an int of pixles. any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With jQuery, you could use `$('td').outerWidth();` You would likely need to add a class to the TD element in order to specify it with your jQuery selector. By the way, this jQuery method uses the outerWidth property "baked in" to JS, but jQuery is easier :)

Comment: Which is great, **if** he's using jQuery. He didn't say he was, and didn't tag the question that way.

Comment: As it happens, he *is* using jQuery; I've updated his question to reflect that.

Comment: outerWidth() doesnt seem to be recognised. i get an error everytime i use it. however, .width works but it returns "12%" not the pixles

Comment: What kind of element is the popup, and what is its parent?

Answer (score 1):

```
var element = document.getElementById('whatever');
//or however you want to get the element
var width;
if (typeof element.clip !== "undefined") { width = element.clip.width; } 
else {
    if (element.style.pixelWidth) { width = element.style.pixelWidth; } 
    else { width = element.offsetWidth; } 
}
```

Comment: OMG. **Never** add anything to the `Object.prototype`. Never. The amount of code you'll break is staggering. (And for this purpose, it won't work in IE anyway, because IE's DOM elements don't use the `Object.prototype`.)

Comment: Since you are using jQuery I would use one of those solutions instead of mine.

Answer (score 0):

jQuery is ideal if you can use it.

```
$('#popupId').width( $('#cellID').width() );
```

or you might need to use `outerWidth()`, depending on your needs.

Comment: Which is great, **if** he's using jQuery. He didn't say he was, and didn't tag the question that way.

Comment: I think i am using query but this doesnt work. is all you need to run jquery is to include it on the head tag like the this? <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.5.js"></script>

Comment: @T.J. Crowder: I clearly stated `jQuery is ideal if you can use it`  @user521180: That should be it. Do your popup div and your destination cell both have IDs??

Comment: Here is a sample of sizing a div to be the same size as a table cell... http://jsfiddle.net/skGDA/1/

Comment: @dutchie432 ive eddited the orginal post. have a look

Comment: Your code works fine if you add `<table><tr>....</tr></table>`. See http://jsfiddle.net/CAnGb/3/

Answer (score 0):

try this ... let me know if it helps

Col Header one
            Col Header two
        
        
            
                abc
                xyz

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" >
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var tableWidth = $('#testTable').outerWidth();
        var thOneWidth = $('#testTable th.#one').outerWidth();
        var thTwoWidth = $('#testTable th.#two').outerWidth();

        alert('Table width : ' + tableWidth + ' \n' + 'Table Col One width : ' + thOneWidth + ' \n' + 'Table Col Two width : ' + thTwoWidth + ' \n');
    });
</script>
```

Comment: I get an error saying "object does not support this property or method"